# Is there a way to listen for the tempo/bpm of audio playing in Android?

Tags: android, media-player, audiotrack, audio-capture

The Android app I'm building has to **listen to music** (either playing on the phone or picked up by the device's mic) and then **do something based on the music**.

So what I was thinking of doing is to **listen for the tempo/bpm of the music playing** and then do some **math** with what I get to influence the background colour of the app.

I need something similar to what [Malcolm McRoberts asked for here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575357/need-android-equivalent-of-audioinputstream) - analyze the music and then do something. He said that he was able to use [Echo Nest](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/) to reach his goals, but he's not explaining how (yet).

I need something very similar to what [elucid135 asked for here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8235575/get-music-tempo-or-bpm) - listen for beats per minute (bpm) and then do animations based on that. But my platform is very different.

Any **Android** ideas?

Perhaps someone with knowledge of Android [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#getPlaybackRate%28%29), [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) or [Audio Capture](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) can give some input.

**EDIT:**

It seemed that no one gets what I'm asking, so I'll try to rephrase:

Using Android, I want to record music via the device's mic. Then I want to analyze what has been recorded to find the beat of the music recorded. Based on that beat, I want stuff to happen in the app.

I know how to record music. What I'm looking for is advice on how to identify the beats in the music.

Hope that clears it up.

Comment: This is a very broad question and we're here for *specific* problems. Casting that aside, you might want to look into the [`Visualizer`-class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html).

Comment: @Lukas Knuth, not sure why you think this question is too broad. I tried to tell why I was asking the question and what research I've done so that people can see that I did my part. The point is that I want to listen for the tempo/bpm of music (either playing on the phone or picked up by the device's mic). I thought that I had made that clear. I'm sorry you felt otherwise.

Comment: It's broad because you didn't implement anything, you're just asking for "how to do?". If you have code and run into a specific problem, we can help with that.

Comment: Many people ask for "how to do" which made me think that it's fine to do that here. Is there another site where I should rather ask "how to do" questions?

Comment: Re: the Visualizer-class: I'm not looking for the frequency because it's not specific to something like the beat of a drum in the audio, and nor can I use the sampling rate because that has to do with when the audio is recorded - not the currently playing audio. So I can't use getFft (byte[] fft) or getSamplingRate () of the Visualizer class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*" has to listen to music"*
...*"either playing on the phone"*
Wont work, Android doesn't support that.

...*"or picked up by the device's mic"*
Will work in some cases (i.e. when using the loudspeaker in a low-noise environment), but quality will be pretty bad.

Another alternative is to use the [Visualizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html) class to grab audio data from session 0 (the global output mix). The quality of the audio will be pretty bad, but it might be good enough for BPM calculation, and it will work even if the music is routed to a headset.

Comment: Hi @Michael,Is there any way to get tempo,mood from audio file android ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a similar problem.  Try looking into TarsosDSP [link](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP).  It is a java based audio signal processing library which provides classes that can identify beats which could then be used to determine tempo and it works with Android.